# How to set up equal height columns with a title on top?

Tags: pages, iwork, text

This is what I'm trying to do on Pages '09: two equal height columns with a title on top. Any suggestions?

[image: Pages screenshot as above]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got it to work — inserted a layout break after my headline and set it up as a one-column layout and the rest of the content as a two-column layout. Applied some padding to it and it's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to Pages at the moment (I'm on an old Macbook on a travel) but a quick fix to your problem would be to set up a text box on top that doesn't allow text to be under it and expand it to cover both columns.

With that said, I'm sure there's a way to set up the columns to behave like that in a more "correct" way, but you'll have to wait until tuesday for me to get back, been offline for almost 30 days and I haven't touched Pages in a while :)

Comment: That would also work, though I don't seem as an appropriate semantic solution to use on a big fat imortant document, as a masters thesis. A good solution, though ;)

Answer (score -1):

page layout- page breaks- continues